# Unable to pivot table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I found this link [Pivot tables in SQL Server. A simple sample.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2009/03/03/pivot-tables-in-sql-server-a-simple-sample.aspx) and did a conversion it to temp table. However, I got an error "Incorrect syntax near '('." Can you help me on this? Below is the code:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DailyIncome') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
drop table #DailyIncome
END

create table #DailyIncome
       (
         VendorId nvarchar(10)
         , IncomeDay nvarchar(10)
         , IncomeAmount int
       )

insert into #DailyIncome values ('SPIKE', 'FRI', 100)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('SPIKE', 'MON', 300)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('FREDS', 'SUN', 400)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('SPIKE', 'WED', 500)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('SPIKE', 'TUE', 200)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('JOHNS', 'WED', 900)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('SPIKE', 'FRI', 100)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('JOHNS', 'MON', 300)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('SPIKE', 'SUN', 400)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('JOHNS', 'FRI', 300)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('FREDS', 'TUE', 500)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('FREDS', 'TUE', 200)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('SPIKE', 'MON', 900)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('FREDS', 'FRI', 900)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('FREDS', 'MON', 500)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('JOHNS', 'SUN', 600)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('SPIKE', 'FRI', 300)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('SPIKE', 'WED', 500)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('SPIKE', 'FRI', 300)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('JOHNS', 'THU', 800)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('JOHNS', 'SAT', 800)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('SPIKE', 'TUE', 100)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('SPIKE', 'THU', 300)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('FREDS', 'WED', 500)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('SPIKE', 'SAT', 100)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('FREDS', 'SAT', 500)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('FREDS', 'THU', 800)
insert into #DailyIncome values ('JOHNS', 'TUE', 600)

SELECT * FROM #DailyIncome

SELECT *
FROM #DailyIncome
pivot(avg(IncomeAmount) FOR IncomeDay IN (
        [MON]
        ,[TUE]
        ,[WED]
        ,[THU]
        ,[FRI]
        ,[SAT]
        ,[SUN]
        )) AS AvgIncomePerDay
```

Thanks guys!

**[UPDATE]**

Based on the comments, the database is created using SQL Server 2000. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you running?

Comment: I just ran this on 2008, 2005 and 2000, and it only failed on 2000. You will notice from the link that PIVOT is only available in 2005+ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx so please run SELECT @@VERSION to check which version this is.

Comment: @Musikero31, your above code is working fine for me.. i executed this in 2005

Comment: It's Sql Server 8.0.2055. Is that Sql Server 2000?

Comment: @Musikero31 , ya 8.0 versions are sql server 2000 only..

Comment: oh shoot! is there a workaround for this?

Comment: Its working perfectly in sql server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like

```
SELECT  VendorId,
        AVG(CASE
            WHEN IncomeDay = 'MON'
                THEN IncomeAmount
            ELSE NULL
        END) [MON],
        AVG(CASE
            WHEN IncomeDay = 'TUE'
                THEN IncomeAmount
            ELSE NULL
        END) [TUE],
        AVG(CASE
            WHEN IncomeDay = 'WED'
                THEN IncomeAmount
            ELSE NULL
        END) [WED],
        AVG(CASE
            WHEN IncomeDay = 'THU'
                THEN IncomeAmount
            ELSE NULL
        END) [THU],
        AVG(CASE
            WHEN IncomeDay = 'FRI'
                THEN IncomeAmount
            ELSE NULL
        END) [FRI],
        AVG(CASE
            WHEN IncomeDay = 'SAT'
                THEN IncomeAmount
            ELSE NULL
        END) [SAT],
        AVG(CASE
            WHEN IncomeDay = 'SUN'
                THEN IncomeAmount
            ELSE NULL
        END) [SUN]
FROM    #DailyIncome
GROUP BY VendorId
```

Please note, the reason why I used NULLS instead of 0 was due to the PIVOT functionality.

from [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

> When aggregate functions are used with PIVOT, the presence of any null
>   values in the value column are not considered when computing an
>   aggregation.

You will find different results if you were to run the query with 0 instead of NULLs

Comment: Of course, your comment about aggregates and null is true outside of the pivot operation as well.

Answer (score 0):

The pivot is much cleaner and fewer lines of code. The syntax was just a little bit off. Try this for your final statement, it wraps the statement in a select clause:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT *
FROM #DailyIncome
)Data
pivot(avg(IncomeAmount) FOR IncomeDay IN (
        [MON]
    ,[TUE]
    ,[WED]
    ,[THU]
    ,[FRI]
    ,[SAT]
    ,[SUN]
    ))
```

AS AvgIncomePerDay